# Stashing a structure variable and using it as a channel parameter

Tags: templates, stash, structure, parse-order

Here's the code i'm essentially trying to achieve

```
{exp:stash:set="page_content"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="photos" dynamaic="off" entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:1}"}
        {!-- My Code --}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

This is my first problem `{structure:child_ids_for:1}` is unable to output as a channel parmater. I tried to stash that structure variable, I tried it as a snippet and no luck with both. I'm also using template partials so that's why `page_content` is being set.

This following code works with static values but not the `{structure:child_ids_for:1}` tag in the stash set.

```
Works:        {exp:stash:set name="photo_child_ids"}2|3|4{/exp:stash:set}
Doesn't Work: {exp:stash:set name="photo_child_ids"}{structure:child_ids_for:1}{/exp:stash:set}
```

**Template Code**

```
{exp:stash:set="page_content"}
    {exp:stash:parse process="end"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="photos" parse="inward" dynamaic="off" entry_id="{stash:photo_child_ids}"}
            {!-- EE Code --}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:parse}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Any Ideas?

---

**EDIT: Thanks for the answers. The solution is below.**

**This stashes the structure child ID tag**

```
{exp:stash:set name="photo_child_ids" process="end" parse_tags="yes"}{structure:child_ids_for:1}{/exp:stash:set}
```

**This code gets that photo_child_ids stash variable and sets it as a parameter**

```
{exp:stash:set name="page_content"}
    {exp:stash:parse process="end"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="photos" parse="inward" dynamic="off" entry_id="{stash:photo_child_ids}"}
            {!-- My Code --}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:parse}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, **dynamic** is misspelled.

Second, Try to add parse_tags="yes" to the stash set.

```
{exp:stash:set="page_content" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="photos" dynamic="off" entry_id="{structure:child_ids_for:1}" parse="inward"}
         {!-- My Code --}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

The parse_tags="yes" tells stash to parse whatever tags are inside rather than simply stashing the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Put the channel entry tags within an embedded template and pass the structure value as embed parameter as

```
{exp:stash:set="page_content"}
{embed="temp_grp/temp_name" entry_ids="{structure:child_ids_for:1}"}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

within "temp_grp/temp_name"

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="photos" dynamic="no" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}" parse="inward"}
{!-- My Code --}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Yea I knew about the embed route. I was trying to avoid using them as much as possible. Stash has been great where it eliminates the need to do that in most cases.